# Is there a way to see a graph of all the edits I made to posts?

Tags: support, edits, statistics

I am asking purely out of my own vanity.

My profile page shows a list of all the posts I have edited, less the ones which got deleted. I usually make a lot of edits to both answers and questions, and it would be nice to see some statistics or data, e.g. how many of the posts I have edited were later deleted (am I editing garbage or are my actions useful). Am I editing more posts now than 6 months ago?

Comment: There is no posthistory in SEDE for deleted posts. I can only whip something together for still visible posts

Comment: Any statistics would be helpful. Ideally they could add some to my profile page :D

Comment: I'd love to see some stats on my edits. I am a keen editor, and I think the kinds of edits I do make a difference, but it would be nice to see how long that material survives.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1119205?UserId=1839439#graph):

```sql
select period
     , [1] [Initial Title]
     , [2] [Initial Body]
     , [3] [Initial Tags]
     , [4] [Edit Title]
     , [5] [Edit Body]
     , [6] [Edit Tags]
     , [7] [Rollback Title]
     , [8] [Rollback Body]
     , [9] [Rollback Tags]
from (
select eomonth(creationdate) [period]
     , count(*) cnt
     , posthistorytypeid 
from posthistory ph
inner join posthistorytypes pt on pt.id = ph.posthistorytypeid
where posthistorytypeid in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
and creationdate > '2019-01-01'
and userid = ##userid?1839439##
group by eomonth(creationdate), posthistorytypeid
) as data
pivot
(
  sum(cnt) 
  for posthistorytypeid in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
) pvt

order by period
```

and today that will give you this graph:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday.